# Issue with capturing image from camera on iPhone

Tags: javascript, mobile, camera

### How to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` correctly? How to deal with portrait and landscape mode on mobile devices?

**Demo code from tutorial website fails for iPhone 8.**

I want to write my own barcode reader in JavaScript to be used on an iPhone. I have coded lots of other JavaScript projects before, so I'm quite experienced with HTML + JavaScript + CSS, but I'm not familiar with accessing the camera via JavaScript. But I found a nice tutorial and hoped to learn from it. But there seems to be an error in this tutorial.

Here is the tutorial: https://usefulangle.com/post/352/javascript-capture-image-from-camera
Here is the demo: https://usefulangle.com/demos/352/camera-capture-photo.html

And here is the complete source code of this demo, as available today, at 2022-05-21 (HTML, CSS and JavaScript are all included in one file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Demo - Capture Photo From Webcam Using Javascript</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
<style type="text/css">

button {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid #111111;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

#start-camera {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#video {
    display: none;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#click-photo {
    display: none;
}

#dataurl-container {
    display: none;
}

#canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#dataurl-header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#dataurl {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<button id="start-camera">Start Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay=""></video>
<button id="click-photo">Click Photo</button>
<div id="dataurl-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <div id="dataurl-header">Image Data URL</div>
    <textarea id="dataurl" readonly=""></textarea>
</div>

<script>

let camera_button = document.querySelector("#start-camera");
let video = document.querySelector("#video");
let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
let dataurl = document.querySelector("#dataurl");
let dataurl_container = document.querySelector("#dataurl-container");

camera_button.addEventListener('click', async function() {
    let stream = null;

    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
        return;
    }

    video.srcObject = stream;

    video.style.display = 'block';
    camera_button.style.display = 'none';
    click_button.style.display = 'block';
});

click_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    
    dataurl.value = image_data_url;
    dataurl_container.style.display = 'block';
});

</script>


</body></html>
```

The problem is, that this demo works well on some of my devices, but fails on others. Among the failing devices it performs worst on iPhone 8, but this is the device I need most to work perfect, because I want to use my iPhone as barcode scanner.

---

### This demo works fine on these platforms:

**Computer: do-it-yourself Hackintosh (MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 on non-Apple hardware)

Camera: logitech HD Webcam C525**
The demo works fine on all of these browsers:

- Safari Version 15.4
- Firefox 100.0.2 (64-Bit)
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.64
- Opera Version:65.0.3467.78

**12 years old Macbook Pro (13 inch, Mid 2010)

MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.7** (unsupported version installed with Catalina Patcher)
The demo works fine on all of these browsers:

- Safari Version 15.4
- Firefox 96.0.1 (64-Bit)
- Firefox 100.0.2 (64-Bit)
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.64

**Notebook "hp Elitebook"

Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H2**
The demo works fine on all of these browsers:

- Microsoft Edge Version 101.0.1210.53
- Firefox 97.0.2 (64-Bit)
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.67

**iPad Pro, 12.9 inch, 3rd generation

iPadOS Version 15.4.1**
The demo works fine on all of these browsers, **but only in portrait mode!**

- Safari 15
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.58

---

### It works with errors on these platforms:

**iPad Pro, 12.9", 3rd generation

iPadOS Version 15.4.1

in landscape mode**
Same error in all browsers: Distorted captured image: The live image is in portrait mode, the captured image is landscape, showing my face double as wide as it really is.

- Safari 15
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.58

**iPhone 8

iOS Version 15.4.1**
The live image is black on all browsers. You see just a black rectangle
In landscape mode: The captured image is ok (user's face is visible and not distorted)
In portrait mode: Distorted captured image (as described for iPad in portrait mode)

- Safari 15
- Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.58

### summary:

Failing does not depend on the browser but on the device. The demo works even on exotic machines like a Hackintosh or a 12 years old Macbook Pro but fails with two different errors on an iPhone 8.

There are two errors:

- Black rectangle instead of live video image
  Only on my iPhone 8. The live video image is visible on all other devices
- Distorted captured still image
  On both mobile devices, but only in portrait mode. It works fine on stationary computer, laptop and Macbook, works also fine in landcape mode on mobile devices.

---

## My question

Please, I need a correction of the demo code, so that it shows the live video image on all devices, including iPhone 8. The corrected code please also shall not show any distorted captured image in portrait mode of mobile devices.

---

**Optional additional question:** (An answer would be nice, but more important is an answer to the issue described above)

I have written a barcode scanner for iPhone 3 and iPhone 4 about 10 years ago in native Objective-C. It was no problem to have a video image 320 pixels wide and only 80 pixels high (to scan EAN-13 and other linear barcodes). Is it possible to have such a 4:1 video window also when using HTML + JavaScript?